# MySQL SUM with 3 relation tables

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables with the following columns, they are:

1. THead - HeadID(PK), padcode, OKqty, TotNGqty
2. TDetail - HeadID(FK), process, name, Subcode
3. TSubDetail - Subcode(FK), NGcode, NGqty

The relations of the 3 tables are like this: THead - TDetail - TSubDetail.

I hope following images can show them clearly.

[image: Tables with sample data]

This is my MySQL Query:

```
SELECT
THead.padcode,
SUM(THead.okqty) AS OK,
SUM(THead.TotNGqty) AS TOTALNG,
SUM(If(TSubDetail.NGCode = 'L3', NGqty, 0)) AS L3

FROM(THead JOIN TDetail ON THead.HeadID = TDetail.HeadID)
                        JOIN TSubDetail ON TDetail.Subcode=TSubDetail.Subcode

GROUP BY padcode
```

I want to sum the OK Qty and TotNGqty without adding the same values from the same TSubDetail.Subcode. I have tried DISTINCT, but that was not a solution.

From the image you can see from the yellow highlight sample:

**For Padcode = 'KVBS-B'**

> I want to get the OK Qty = 2845 and the Sum NG from Table Head = 705.
>
> But from the query above, i got the wrong result, OK = 3245 and NG =
>   905.

I know that the same values from the same TSubDetail.Subcode was added multiple times. But what is the correct query so i can get the true result?

I hope someone can help me and explain what is the correct query. Thanks in advance for helping me.

Comment: Is padcode unique in THead ?

Comment: @forpas seems like it's not according to sample data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a correlated subquery in the SELECT clause. This way `okqty` and `TotNGqty` won't be multiplied by the number of related rows in `TSubDetail`.

```
SELECT
    THead.padcode,
    SUM(THead.okqty) AS OK,
    SUM(THead.TotNGqty) AS TOTALNG,
    SUM((
        SELECT SUM(TSubDetail.NGqty)
        FROM TDetail
        JOIN TSubDetail ON TDetail.Subcode=TSubDetail.Subcode
        WHERE THead.HeadID = TDetail.HeadID
          AND TSubDetail.NGCode = 'L3'
    )) AS L3 
FROM THead
GROUP BY padcode
```

Or aggregate twice. First get `SUM(TSubDetail.NGqty)` in a derived table. Then JOIN it with the `THead` in the outer query:

```
SELECT
    THead.padcode,
    SUM(THead.okqty) AS OK,
    SUM(THead.TotNGqty) AS TOTALNG,
    SUM(x.L3) as L3
FROM THead
LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT TDetail.HeadID, SUM(TSubDetail.NGqty) as L3
    FROM TDetail
    JOIN TSubDetail ON TDetail.Subcode=TSubDetail.Subcode
    WHERE TSubDetail.NGCode = 'L3'
    GROUP BY TDetail.HeadID
) x ON x.HeadID = THead.HeadID
GROUP BY THead.padcode
```

Comment: Thank you so much @paul-spiegel. Your both answers generate the right result.
Since i've tried the code, and i got the NULL result for L3 column, i must use COALESCE function.

And since i want to add another column like L3, i will use the upper answer.
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

If you select this, you can see which lines are double, and therefore will be counted double:

```
SELECT
  THead.padcode,
  THead.okqty,
  THead.TotNGqty
  TDetail.HeadID,
  TsubDetail.Subcode,
  If(TSubDetail.NGCode = 'L3', NGqty, 0) AS L3
FROM THead 
  JOIN TDetail ON THead.HeadID = TDetail.HeadID
  JOIN TSubDetail ON TDetail.Subcode=TSubDetail.Subcode
```

Answer (score 0):

You are showing a subset of your data, so it is difficult to answer definitively, but your GROUP BY clause includes only 'padcode' column and not the HeadID column.

I assume that in the whole table you have records with the same padcode (KVBS-B) for multiple HeadIDs, not only for those shown in yellow. As a result they get summed as well, but you can't see which ones, because of the too general GROUP BY.

Answer (score 0):

Given the query above is what's required and there aren't any additional constraints.
You can do this by running two queries.

For the first query, you can get the sum OK and TOTALNG by grouping padcode and not joining in on other tables. And for the second query get the sum L3 by joining tables and finally joining the above two queries by padcode.